# Is there a way to "update" RDS files by combining them with another RDS file?

Tags: r

I need to be able to merge RDS files so I do not have to run a SQL statement which takes 1 hour to run every day.

I have only been able to save and read separate RDS files. I am using R version 3.5.3 and I have not been able to find anything on updating files.

I tried `merge(datafile1, datafile2)` and this returned no data.

Comment: rds files can only hold a single object (.rda or .RData files can hold multiple objects). Do you want to combine the objects in the two .rds files, e.g. by using `rbind()` on two commensurate data frames?  Are the objects small enough that it's convenient to load them both into R at the same time?